# Basic topology questions with cantor's set

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I have 3 questions in toplogy, one of which I managed to solve (but would appreciate input regardless) and 2 which are more difficult. I'd like a push in the right direction.

Define $K$ as ternary cantor set (meaning u always take the middle third out).

1) Show that $\Omega = [0,1]\setminus K$ is an open set.

2) Show that $\partial \Omega = K$. If I understood correctly, $\partial$ means the closure.

3) Show that $K$ has no isolated points

What I did:

1) $K$ is a closed set, and $[0,0],[1,1] \in K$. so $[0,1] \setminus K = (0,1) \setminus K$.

$(0,1)$ is an open set, and since $K$ is closed, $K^c$ is open. $(0,1) \setminus K = (0,1) \cap K^c$ is the intersection of two open sets, which is an open set.

2) I don't think this makes any sense. $\Omega$ doesn't have any element in common with $K$. How can $K$ be the closure of $\Omega$? Wouldn't that imply that $\Omega \subseteq K$? Maybe I misunderstood the notation

3) I'm clueless.

Comment: You have an error in 2). $\partial \Omega=\overline{\Omega}\setminus int(\Omega)$

Comment: Are you familiar with base 3? There is a nifty construction of the standard Cantor set which makes use of base 3, and I think it could prove much useful in proving 3). (:

Comment: What does $\bar \Omega$ stand for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following hints will, I think, help you get started-

**(1)** The complement of the cantor set in $\displaystyle [0,1]$ is a union of open intervals.

**(2)** Try and show that the cantor set has an empty interior, which means that the Cantor set does not contain any non-empty open interval. Try and arrive at  a contradiction by assuming otherwise.

**(3)** Let $x\in K$ and consider an open neighbourhood $U(x,\epsilon)$. Show that this neighbourhood contains  elements of $K$ other than $x$ and that this is true for all $\epsilon > 0$, which implies that $x$ is not an isolated point.